# Check if class exists

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong? I create class - discount, and if this class exists, I want to create element below.

```
if (isRangeWithinRange(valueRange, dateRange)) {
  classes.push('discount');
} else if ($(".discount")[0]) {
  React.createElement('div');
}
```

I created class discount and now i want to receive something like this inside the button if class 'discount' exists:

```
<button class="discount">
  <div></div>
</button>
```

My HTML looks like

```html
<button class="react-calendar__tile react-calendar__tile--active discount react-calendar__tile--range react-calendar__month-view__days__day" 
type="button" style="flex-basis: 14.2857%; max-width: 14.2857%; overflow: hidden;">
  <abbr aria-label="30 grudnia 2020">30</abbr>
</button>
```

Comment: Where is `classes` declared? It looks like a simple array.

Comment: @terrymorse classes are declared to className:
  var classes = [className];

Comment: `className` is a string. I don't see how appending to an array that contains the `className` string would modify `className`. Is this some sort of React magic?

Comment: `"".concat('discount')` why.....

Comment: jQuery with React..... why?

Comment: I just want to create a div in every element where class "discount" exists. class "discount" was created and implemented with code above.

Comment: Does this help: [How do I add CSS classes to components?](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-styling.html)

Comment: Why are you not doing this in react? Simple if in the jsx....

Comment: it doesn't help me. that's how my html look like:
`<button class="react-calendar__tile react-calendar__tile--active discount react-calendar__tile--range react-calendar__month-view__days__day" type="button" style="flex-basis: 14.2857%; max-width: 14.2857%; overflow: hidden;"><abbr aria-label="30 grudnia 2020">30</abbr></button>`

i want to create div inside the button if class 'discount' exists.
to let it be like this:
<button>
<div></div>
<abbr></abbr>
</button>

Comment: @epascarello because i don't know how the hell receive this, can u help me to find the solution in react?

Comment: First things first. Can you verify that your code actually adds `class="discount"` to a button element? I doubt it does, not with the code supplied.

Comment: @terrymorse yes it does.

Comment: What is the code in react that outputs the button? How is the class added?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add a `<div>` to every `.discount` element, you could go with this:

```
if ($(".discount").length > 0){
    $(".discount").append('<div></div>')
}
```

Comment: `if ($(".discount").length>0)`

Comment: @Isman F. it generates an infinite number of divs

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce that, here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ojf245aL/